# custom bindings div using Knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0, jplayer

I am using knockout js jplayer from this link "https://github.com/scommisso/knockout-jplayer",its working fine,but when i have more than one  audio url everything is binding inside the same div rather than getting linked to other div

```
     //Html foreach binding//
<div data-role="content" style="background-color: #fff !important;" data- bind="foreach:AudioList">
<div data-bind="jplayer: {media: { mp3: ogg } }">
</div>

    //Creating ViewModel
function ViewModel() {
var self = this;
 self.AudioList= ko.observableArray([]);

var sampleData = [{ ogg: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-04- Lismore1.ogg" },
    { ogg: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-04-Lismore2.ogg" },
    { ogg: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-04-Lismore3.ogg" }
];
self.AudioList($.map(sampleData, function (item) {
    return new AudioListViewModel(item);
}));

function AudioListViewModel(data) {
var self = this;
self.ogg = ko.observable(data.ogg);
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());

  //The output which we are currently getting//

    <div data-role="content" style="background-color: #fff !important;" data- bind="foreach:AudioList">
  <div data-bind="jplayer: {media: { mp3: ogg } }">
  <div id="jplayer1"><audio url="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-04- Lismore1.ogg""></audio></div>
 <div id="jplayer2"><audio url="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-04- Lismore2.ogg""></audio></div>
 <div id="jplayer3"><audio url="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-04-  Lismore3.ogg""></audio></div>
  </div>

  //Expected output//

 <div data-role="content" style="background-color: #fff !important;" data- bind="foreach:AudioList">
 <div data-bind="jplayer: {media: { mp3: ogg } }">
 <div id="jplayer1"><audio url="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-04- Lismore1.ogg""></audio></div>
</div>

  <div data-role="content" style="background-color: #fff !important;" data- bind="foreach:AudioList">
<div data-bind="jplayer: {media: { mp3: ogg } }">
<div id="jplayer2"><audio url="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-04- Lismore2.ogg""></audio></div>
</div>

 <div data-role="content" style="background-color: #fff !important;" data- bind="foreach:AudioList">
<div data-bind="jplayer: {media: { mp3: ogg } }">
<div id="jplayer3"><audio url="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-04- Lismore3.ogg""></audio></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your HTML to this -

```
<div data- bind="foreach:AudioList">
    <div data-role="content" style="background-color: #fff !important;"></div>
    <div data-bind="jplayer: {media: { mp3: ogg } }"></div>
</div>
```

You might need to do some css related changes..

Comment: @thnks for your time,its not working for me,wat might be the main problem